# Exchange 2010 email forward with filter

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, mail-forwarding

Is it possible to create an on-server rule to distribute/forward incoming email to certain mailboxes **based on sender's email address.**

Example, user1@domain.com sends an email to @user2@domain.com, and I would like for all emails from this user sent to user2@domain.com, to end up in user3@domain.com mailbox

I do not want to do a client forwarding. I would like to to it on server in Exchange 2010.

Comment: See similar question: http://serverfault.com/q/392736/3139. Not closing as duplicate, though.

Comment: This is nothing to do with that question, I am still looking for an answer. I did not think this is such a rare case.

Answer (score 1):

you can configure transport rules on HT, to relay all mails from user1@ to user2@ to be forwarded to user3@

Guide here:
http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/using-transport-rules-to-moderate-messages-using-exchange-server-2010.html